# Calling Jquery from an ASP.net treenode in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, hyperlink, treenode

I am having problems calling a jquery function from an asp.net treenode control.
Here is the treenode code in the aspx file.
The method I am using is to put a javascript link in the "navigateUrl" attribute.

Below is the code:

```
<asp:TreeNode Value="Level1" 
                NavigateUrl="javascript:$('#mainContentContainer').load('report.aspx?level=1');"
                Text="Level 1"
                Target="Content"
                expanded="false">
```

This works perfectly in CHROME. The report.aspx content loads into the mainContentContainer div as expected when I click on the treenode "Level 1".

In Internet Explorer however (v8 and 9), it just opens another browser window and attempts to load the JavaScript link as if it were a URL. For some reason the address bar only shows this portion of the link: "javascript:$('" and the content window gives this error "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

I have searched for this problem and all solutions I found suggest either using the "OnClick" attribute to make the JavaScript call or to set the "target" attribute of the " element to "_self"

Neither of these options worked for me. I can not give the  tag an "OnClick" attribute because it is not a valid attribute for this asp.net control.

Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode' does not have a public property named 'onclick'
is the error that appears in the browser (returned as the standard .net error webpage)

I tried the target="_self" option and the only change was that instead of a new browser window opening with an error. The current browser will just display [object Object] without any change in the address bar.

Another solution I read was to put "retun false" after the javascript call but this gives a "return statement outside of function" javascript error.

Please let me know if there is a solution to call jquery.load from an asp.net treenode control.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the following solution, which is to use jQuery after the document is loaded or after the tree is rendered to bind a click event handler. So instead of the `javascript:` inside the `NavigateUrl` attribute, you just use the actual url of the report.

```
<asp:TreeNode Value="Level1" 
  NavigateUrl="report.aspx?level=1"
  Text="Level 1"
  Target="Content"
  Expanded="false">
```

Normally, this would result in a navigation away from the page and to the report page. But we can prevent this using the following jQuery code to add the click event handler to the link:

```
$("#tree a").click(function(e) {
  // Get the url (report.aspx?level=...)
  var url = $(this).attr("href");

  // Load the report
  $('#mainContentContainer').load(url);

  // Don't navigate away
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

You may have to use a more specific selector to only add this click handler to nodes at a certain level in your tree. In that case, you can give these nodes a class using [`LevelStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.levelstyles.aspx) and then use a different selector in jQuery:

```
<div id="tree">
  <asp:TreeView runat="server">
    <LevelStyles>
      <!-- Add class report only to nodes at the first level -->
      <asp:TreeNodeStyle CssClass="report"/>
    </LevelStyles>
    ...
  </asp:treeView>
</div>
```

Now your jQuery selector would be:

```
$("#tree .report a").click(function(e) { ... });
```